# Add all users from an organization to a Google Group

Tags: google-groups, google-apps-for-work

In my Google Apps directory, I have 5 user organizations.  I would like to have a group for each organization.  Is there a way that I can create a group that automatically adds all the users from a particular organization to that group?

I know I can create a group that adds all users from my domain, but that is not what I am after.  I would like 5 groups, each with the users from their own organization.